# ionic 3 - What is the best practice to share variables across the application

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

For ionic 3 - what is the best practice to share variables across the application?
For example, if I have a generic variable or generic array and I want it to be available across all source files in the application, what is the best way to do it?

Should I use a provider and create getter functions or maybe there is some better and simple way to do it, such like header files in c?

Comment: The [tag:angularjs] tag is for angular 1.x only, for Angular 2+ use tag: [tag:angular]

Comment: It depends on your use case but some of the more common methods are covered [here in the Stack Overflow documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular/10836/sharing-data-among-components#t=201707280041088605019)

Comment: great examples, but why there is no use of provider? maybe this is a difference between angular and ionic? that angular use service while ionic use provider?

Comment: provider and service are the same thing - Ionic is built on Angular 2 :)

Comment: ionic 3 is based on angular 4

Comment: Yes sorry, however since they moved to semver there isn't much difference (at least not compared to AngularJS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would follow the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#core-feature-module) for the Core-feature model. Which means creating a common module for your application wide singleton services (providers). Where you import those services and add them to the `providers`-list.
Then simply import the `CoreModule` in the `AppModule`, eg add it to the `imports`-list.

**Core-module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FooService } from './services/foo-service';
import { BarService } from './services/bar-service';

export {
    FooService,
    BarService
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        IonicModule
    ],
    providers: [
        FooService,
        BarService
    ]
})
export class CoreModule{}
```

By adding the

```
export {
    FooService,
    BarService
}
```

you can import all the services in your components from one file, like this:

```
import { FooService, BarService } from '../../core/core-module';
```

And inject and use them as usual in the `constructor`:

```
constructor(private fooService: FooService, private barService:BarService){}

someFunctionCallingServiceFunction(){
    this.fooService.data; // You can access properties
    this.fooService.someFunction(); // and functions 
}
```

The file structure I use:

```
--core/
  core.module.ts
  --services/
    foo.service.ts
    bar.service.ts
```

**Example service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FooService {
    data:string;
    private hiddenData:string; // Can only be used internally

    constructor(){ }

    someFunction(){
        // Does something...
    }

    // Can only be used internally
    private somePrivateFunction(){
        // Does something else...
    }
}
```

Comment: so we must use the "service" mechanism which is a class and import this class, and set getter function to get the generic variable?

Comment: You are demonstrate function use, but I asked about variable sharing. If you are saying that var sharing need to be by using functions so this is what I wrote that we need getter function. But I think we can use variables directly. Something like *this.fooService.someVar*. What do you thing?

Comment: Yes you can use property, just as you say, a getter function is not a must. I will update my answer.

Comment: Had any success yet?

Comment: I think I will do that, but it seems to me not good approach and I hope that in the next angular versions they will make an easier way to create a generic variables. It should be a simple thing just like header file